# AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am working on parsing a website in my application.

This is the website: https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json

Since I have had some trouble with this, I first tried to get the entire website using a class that extends AsyncTask.

Here is the code which gets EVERYTHING from the website above:

```
     private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls)
        {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try
            {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

However, if you go to the website, I only want the portion after rates. I have to edit the above code so it only returns what I need.

Based on what I understand, I know that I need to change String response to an ArrayList, and I need to change the while loop, but I don't know what I should do exactly.

I tried using the following code to change the method, but it did NOT work.

```
     private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        ArrayList<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String url : urls)
        {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try
            {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = response.toString();
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(s);
                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                        response.add(jo.getString("rates"));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

@Dheeraj, UPDATE:

```
   while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
   {
         JSONArray ja = new JSONObject().getJSONArray("rates"); 
        response.add(ja.toString()); 
   }
```

This is what I have so far Dheeraj. I am stuck on how to provide the buffer to a JSONObject. Can you help me?

Comment: It ran and it did not give me any error, but when I added this method:

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){ 
   tv.setText(result.get(0)); } This means that result does not contain anything (IndexOutofBoundsException was thrown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Provide the entire buffer you get from the network to a
   [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).
2. [**Edit:** Corrected thanks to @MisterSquonk] From the `JSONObject` get the value of "rates" as another `JSONObject` using [`getJSONObject("rates")`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29).
3. Iterate over the keys of the "rates" object to get its values.

Here's the code:

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ArrayList<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(content);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                while (isr.read(buffer) != -1) {
                    sb.append(buffer);
                }
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                JSONObject ratesObj = jobj.getJSONObject("rates");
                Iterator<String> keys = ratesObj.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    response.add(ratesObj.getString(keys.next()));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a JSON parsing library is exactly what you want to do here. The code you provided above is really reinventing the wheel because there are already robust solutions to your problem. Use the library, no headaches!

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could write what you have stated into code. I am unsure how to code what you said. Thank you.

Comment: @user1193587 I'd like to help you if you can try to code it and post any issues you face.

Comment: @Dheeraj: the value of "rates" isn't a JSONArray - it's a JSONObject with multiple key/value pairs. It's bounded by `{}` and not `[]`

Comment: MisterSquonk and Dheeraj, that means that the update posted to my original question is not correct. So then what should I do?

Comment: @user1193587: Don't use your second method to try and parse the JSON dynamically. As Dheeraj says in his/her point 1, use your first method to read the entire webpage as a `String` then create a `JSONObject` with that. Then use `getJSONObject("rates")` to return its value as a new JSONObject (called `ratesObject` for example). Then use something like `for(String currency : ratesObject.keys())` to iterate through the keys and get the individual 'rate' values.

Comment: Ok I will try this and get back to you. Thanks MisterSquonk.

Comment: ratesObject.keys() does not work, it says that it can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable.

Comment: Dheeraj, thank you so much! Your code works, and I am EXTREMELY grateful for your efforts in helping me understand parsing a JSON file. Thank you!

Comment: Appending the whole buffer might get you into problems if you try to parse the last part of the stream. The web page is unlikely to be split equally into 1KB buffers. Your last buffer will thus contain some garbage. The read() method returns the number of characters that were put into the buffer. A typical code would look like this :
int readCount = 0; while ((readCount = reader.read(buffer)) >= 0) { builder.append(buffer, 0, readCount); }